# using reference commands in a tabular environment

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

In a table, I would like to include a page reference to a particular section of my document. Unfortunately, only the `\nameref` command resolves after compiling multiple times. The `\ref` and `\pageref` commands always generate ?? inside the table, even though they work fine outside of the table. Is there a way to update the ref and pageref commands to work inside the table?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{@{} lll @{}} 
     \toprule
      nameref & pageref  & ref \\
   \midrule
      \nameref{lec1} & \pageref{{lec1}}  & \ref{{lec1}} \\
   \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
   \caption{nameref works, but pageref and ref don't work}
   \label{tab:refs}
\end{table}
\section{The First Section}\label{lec1}
\end{document}
```

The code above generates the following, even after compiling many times:
[image]

Comment: The problem is the double braces. Replace `\pageref{{lec1}}` by `\pageref{lec1}` and it will work (notice that the first `\nameref` has only one pair of braces and it worked).

Comment: Oh duh, thank you! I didn't even notice I had double braces in there. Works great now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments. The `\ref` was not working because of extra pairs of braces.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - Phelype Oleinik pointed out the non-working commands had double braces.